# Laravel 5 - validator for current user password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have password change form and there's two fields in it: `old_password` and `new_password`.

I'm stuck with validator for old password, here's what I done:

```php
Validator::extend('old_password', function($attribute, $value) use ($user) {
    return $user->password === Hash::make($value);
});
```

But `Hash::make($value)` always generates different result with the same `$value`.

How can I make validator to match current user password?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use [`Hash::check( $plaintext, $hashed )`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing) instead:

```
return Hash::check( $value, $user->password );
```